# Lichess summary analyzer tool

Tags: opening, analysis, lichess

I'm trying to find an online tool that I had once used to analyze my games. It allowed me to import thousands of my games from Lichess and showed what my most common opening mistakes were. The only thing it needed was my Lichess user name.

I had learned about that tool from an Eric Rosen twitch stream. I used it only once on that day. It's been a while since then and I've forgotten the name of the website. I tried searching for various keywords but I'm unable to find it. Maybe it's not visible to search engines?

I would like to know what website it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for [OpeningTree](https://www.openingtree.com/)
[image: OpeningTree.com]